# Multiple Rows with in SQL INSTEAD of Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

looking a bit of direction or guidance as to why I’m getting multiple rows using my trigger.  Basically I have a web app that controls Asset Types (i.e Laptops, Phones etc), what I’m trying to do with this trigger is when the Asset Type Name (at_typedesc) changes that I log to an audit table (in this case sql_log) what the old name was and what the new name is.

This is working, but for some reason I get multiple lines written at the INSERT TO SQL_LOG statement.  It does write the old name & new name, but then I’ll get 3 additional rows which has the old name showing the new name...

This is currently on a 2008 SQL Server.

```
-- create the trigger

go
create trigger trg_InsteadOfUpdate on [dbo].[lkp_asset_types]
instead of update
as

    begin

            DECLARE @triggerAction varchar(1)

            -- determine the TRIGGER action
            -- this allows us to tell if its an INSERT or an UPDATE
            SELECT @triggerAction = CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
            AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted) THEN 'U'
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted) THEN 'I'
            ELSE 'D' END;

            -- get the orginally asset name from the DELETED table
            -- this contains the rows as they were BEFORE the UPDATE Statement
            DECLARE @orgAssetTypeName varchar(255)
            SET @orgAssetTypeName = (SELECT top 1 at_typedesc from lkp_asset_types WHERE at_id = (select at_id from deleted))

            -- UPDATE to the new asset name based on the NEW value in the INSERTED Table
            update lkp_asset_types
            set at_typedesc = (select at_typedesc from inserted)
            where at_id = (select at_id from inserted)

            -- get the new asset name from the INSERTED table
            -- this contains the rows as they were AFTER the UPDATE Statement
            DECLARE @newAssetTypeName varchar(255)
            SET @newAssetTypeName = (SELECT top 1 at_typedesc from lkp_asset_types WHERE at_id = (select at_id from inserted))

            insert into sql_log
            (sql_log)
            values ('SQL PRE Changed from : ' + @orgAssetTypeName + ' to: ' + @newAssetTypeName + '.  Action = ' + @triggerAction)

    end
go
```

Comment: You have many problems in the code. But let's ignore that and look at the one you report. You say there are mulitple log rows - so provide a complete example. Did you verify that the code works correctly when executing a single row update statement using SSMS?

Comment: The issue currently occurs when I perform a single update statement on a single row.  I must add this is a small dev application and my first attempt at an instead of trigger, using a YouTube video as a guide.

Comment: Such general comments are not particularly helpful. To be frank, writing triggers correctly is a topic that requires a solid foundation of tsql skills. Writing intead-of triggers is more difficult than writing after triggers - so i have to question this approach generally. Auditing is generally done using after triggers - a little searching will find many examples. And, of course, i must highlight the fact that 2008 is completely unsupported. You also have a normalization issue which is somewhat relevant as well.

Answer (score 1):

Logic like this in a trigger in SQL Server is just broken:

```
       where at_id = (select at_id from inserted)
```

I really wish the SQL Server parser issued a warning when encountering such constructs.

There is no guarantee that `inserted` has only one value (nor `deleted`).

That is how SQL Server defines triggers:  as *set* operations.  If multiple rows are inserted at the same, then the `inserted` and `deleted` "tables" have multiple rows.

That part is simple.  You will need to rewrite the trigger to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

On checking my web code the update button was performing additional updates, this caused the trigger to fire more than once thus causing duplicate rows.

Answer (score -3):

```
create table dbo.lkp_asset_types_test
(
at_id int identity,
at_typedesc varchar(100)
)
go

create trigger trg_InsteadOfUpdate_test on [dbo].[lkp_asset_types_test]
instead of update
as
begin

    select 'trigger fired!!!!'

    if not exists(select * from inserted)
    and not exists(select * from deleted)
    begin
        return;
    end

    --update (maybe only the diffs?)
    update t
    set at_typedesc = i.at_typedesc
    from dbo.lkp_asset_types_test as t
    join inserted as i on t.at_id = i.at_id;
    --where t.at_typedesc <> i.at_typedesc & nulls??

    --insert into sql_log(sql_log)
    select
        'SQL PRE Changed from : ' + isnull(d.at_typedesc, '*null*') + ' to: ' + isnull(i.at_typedesc, '*null*') + '.  Action = U'
    from inserted as i
    join deleted as d on i.at_id = d.at_id
    --where i.at_typedesc <> d.at_typedesc & nulls ??
end
go


insert into dbo.lkp_asset_types_test(at_typedesc) values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), (NULL);
go

update dbo.lkp_asset_types_test
set at_typedesc = case when at_id%2=0 then isnull(at_typedesc, 'X') else isnull(at_typedesc, '') + 'xyz' end
go

select *
from dbo.lkp_asset_types_test;
go

update dbo.lkp_asset_types_test
set at_typedesc = case when at_id%2=0 then at_typedesc else at_typedesc + 'xyz' end
where 1=2
go

--
drop table lkp_asset_types_test;
```

Comment: Code-only answers are highly discouraged. They teach very little - which should be a goal when providing an answer. What they should NOT do is encourage bad habits or use code that might break applications. One should not return a resultset from a trigger in a production system - as you have done here. For debugging it might be OK, but you did not mention that. You added logic for NULL values but did mention anything specific about that beyond cryptic comments. You added schema-qualification to table but did not mention it.

Comment: Performing `SELECT` statements is deprecated and it is *strongly* recommended that you don't do it. If you *must* denote the trigger has fired, use `PRINT`, not `SELECT`. The other `SELECT` I would just remove if it's not going to perform an `INSERT`.